# Sum one column and subtract over second column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I want to display the subtraction of two columns. From the first column I need to get sum all value and substract with each value from the second column.

This is the table structure:

```
id | name | col1  | col2 | date
------------------------------------
432| xxx  | 0     | 15   |2015-11-17
432| yyy  | 10    | 30   |2015-11-19 
432| zzz  | 60    | 40   |2015-11-20  

433| aaa  | 0     | 60   |2015-11-17
433| bbb  | 80    | 20   |2015-11-19 
433| ccc  | 60    | 10   |2015-11-20
```

Formula should go:

```
sum(col1) = 70  =>>>   WHERE ID = 432  

70 - col2            col3
-------------------------
=> 70 - 15         =  55
=> 70 - (30 + 15)  =  25 
=> 70 - (40 + 45)  = -15
---------------------------

sum(col1) = 140  ===>>    WHERE ID = 433  

 140 -   col2         col3
-------------------------
=> 140 -  60        =  80
=> 140 - (60 + 20)  =  60 
=> 140 - (10 + 80)  =  50
```

result is col3 and Output should be like as

```
id | name | col1  | col2 | col3 |    date
-------------------------------------------
432| xxx  | 0     | 15   |  55  |  2015-11-17
432| yyy  | 10    | 30   |  25  |  2015-11-19 
432| zzz  | 60    | 40   | -15  |  2015-11-20  

433| aaa  | 0     | 60   |  80  |  2015-11-17
433| bbb  | 80    | 20   |  60  |  2015-11-19 
433| ccc  | 60    | 10   |  50  |  2015-11-20
```

---

EDIT: What if I need the values ​​vary depending on the group as a 432 and 433 id column.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Schema Info**

```
DECLARE @TEST TABLE
  (
     id INT,
     name VARCHAR(10),
     col1       INT,
     col2        int
  ) 

INSERT INTO @TEST VALUES 
(432,'xxx',0, 15 ),
(432,'yyy',10, 30 ),
(432,'zzz',60, 40 ),
(433,'aaa',0, 60 ),
(433,'bbb',80, 20 ),
(433,'ccc',60, 10 )
```

**Query**

```
    SELECT  T.id ,
        T.name ,
        T.col1 ,
        T.col2 ,
        SUM(T.col1) OVER( PARTITION BY T.id ORDER BY T.id ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
        - SUM(T.col2) OVER ( PARTITION BY T.id ORDER BY T.id ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW ) AS col3
FROM    @TEST T;
```

**Results**

```
id | name | col1  | col2 | col3 |
---------------------------------
432  | xxx  | 0     | 15   |  55  |
432  | yyy  | 10    | 30   |  25  |
432  | zzz  | 60    | 40   | -15  |
433  | aaa  | 0     | 60   |  80  | 
433  | bbb  | 80    | 20   |  60  | 
433  | ccc  | 60    | 10   |  50  |
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7dac3)**

Comment: @sqlProfile87: Then you have to use partition by clause for my query. wait  i will update my answer in few minuites

Comment: @sqlProfile87: I have updated my answer. Check sql fiddle link for result

Answer (score 1):

You can use two subqueries in SELECT fields list.

With the first you'll get a sum of all rows of your table named yourtable, in the second you'll get a sum of all rows before the current. So you can subtract two values.

Try this:

```
SELECT T.id, T.name, T.col1, T.col2,
ISNULL(
    (SELECT SUM(T2.col1) FROM yourtable T2)
,0) - 
ISNULL(
    (SELECT SUM(T3.col2) FROM yourtable T3 
    WHERE T3.id <= T.id)
,0) as col3,
t.date
FROM yourtable T
```

Go on [**Sql fiddle example**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d6b28/1/0)

**EDIT**

```
SELECT T.id, T.name, T.col1, T.col2,
ISNULL(
    (SELECT SUM(T2.col1) FROM yourtable T2 where T2.id = T.id)
,0) - 
ISNULL(
    (SELECT SUM(T3.col2) FROM yourtable T3 
    WHERE T3.id = T.id AND T3.date <= T.date)
,0) as col3,
t.date
FROM yourtable T
```

Go on [**Sql Fiddle edited example**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fac36/3/0)

**Pay attention:** A deep edit can be a different question. Two queries are differents

**Pay attention:** it's no good a field named ID with repeated values

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
declare @total int = (select sum(col1) from Table)
select id, name, col1, col2, @total - (select sum(col2) from Table where date <= T.date) as col3, date from Table T
```

I was assuming you want to substract every time the previous total (based on the date). I hope this is OK.

Comment: I advice to use id field instead of date. If you have two rows with the same date...

Comment: @JoeTaras It really depends on what he needs. Same date should not be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple select query with cross apply

```
    SELECT ID
    ,NAME
    ,COL1
    ,COL2
    ,A.C1 - (
        SUM(COL2) OVER (
            ORDER BY ID
            )
        ) AS COL3
FROM TABLE1 T1
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT SUM(COL1) AS C1
    FROM TABLE1 T2
    ) A
```